# How to declare variables in custom VueJS directives?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've got an error when tried to declare a variable in the usual way like this:

```
   Vue.directive('my-directive', {
        varA: '', 
        inserted: function(el, binding, vnode){
              this.varA = 'test'; // TypeError: Cannot set property 
                                  // 'varA ' of undefined
        },
    });
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'varA ' of undefined

How do you declare variables in Vue directives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Vue directives, when you need to store a value it is generally stored on the *element*.

```
Vue.directive('my-directive', {
  inserted: function(el, binding, vnode){
    el.varA = 'test'; 
  },
});
```

The element is passed in as an argument to each of the lifecycle events in a directive and you can access the value later from `el.varA`.

Comment: Is it bad decision to save state inside directive?  Can you tell about your opinion / attitude about this.  Should we create a vue component instead? Or that's depends on programmer preferences, only. (see @user1585345 comment).

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko I don't use directives very often at all. I find in almost all cases I can make a component that does what I need. I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing to store state in a directive, I just don't find the need often.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be 2 ways for this:

1. According to this [comment on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6385#issuecomment-323141918), you may define a stateful directive like this:

   ```
   Vue.directive('my-directive', (() => {
       let varA = '';
       return {
           inserted: function(el, binding, vnode){
               varA = 'test'; 
           },
       };
   })());
   ```
2. According to a note box on [Vue.js docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments):

   > If you need to share information across hooks, it is recommended to do so through element’s [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

   ```
   Vue.directive('my-directive', {
       inserted: function(el, binding, vnode){
           el.dataset.varA = 'test'; 
       },
   });
   ```

Comment: the first approach is not a "stateful" directive per definition. `varA` is a variable that has the same state for every directive of the kind `my-directive`. If you need a state save it to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` is not what you think it is. If you do `console.log(this)` inside your function, you'll see that `this` is the window.

Looking at [the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html), directives are for '...cases where you just need some low-level DOM access on plain elements'. So there's no provision for directives to have state. I suspect you need a component, not a directive. What are you trying to do? You can go a long way in vue without ever needing to write a directive.

Comment: I was going to store some HTML element initial  states inside directive, before they will be changed by directive. I wanted to have opportunity to set those initial states back when I need that. That was the main reason why I was going  to use directive state.

Comment: That sounds a little louche to me! You should be trying to keep all your state in a viewmodel, and trying to avoid event handlers. The markup should be dumb, stateless, and reactive. Why not add an `initialState` property to your viewModel, then, when you need to, `state = initialState`, and the changes flow onto your page.